# Azure Push Notification REST No Service is Hosted at the Specified Address

Tags: rest, azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure mobile services to do Push Notifications. I have a push notification service bus created. When I try to connect to that through a REST service I get the following response:

```
404No service is hosted at the specified address. TrackingId:dfc9aea1-e229-4eb7-b393-c8cd6bce258d_G19,TimeStamp:11/3/2014 8:39:21 PM
```

The POSTMAN request looks like so which duplicates the problem:
[image]

How do I further troubleshoot this because the service is there? What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A reference to the above API can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223266.aspx

After troubleshooting with Microsoft we found the problem to be two-fold.

The Connection String key you should be using is found on the hubs page. Named `DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature`.

The next thing is the hub name shouldn't be the namespace.
In my URI…

https://qb-alphahub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/**qb-alphahub-ns**/messages/?api-version=2013-10

Should be

https://qb-alphahub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/**qb-alphahub**/messages/?api-version=2013-10

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue when sending requests via Python and Postman.

I tried the above solution with no luck. My issue ended up being two-fold as well:

1. My namespace was named the same as my notification hub. Had to rename my hub.
2. I had to add an extra header to the POST: `"X-WNS-Type": "wns/toast"`

After making the changes, my toast notifications started working with successful responses from the Notification Hub web services.